# Corda - State size information

Tags: blockchain, corda

Is there any way to get the **size** of a **Corda State**?

I need to know how much space my State takes up in the ledger but I don't know how to get that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complicated. A state in a CorDapp is a simple Java class, but its information is spread in multiple tables, depending on its history, its status that changes and on how you use that state  (e.g. if you make a token out of it with Token SDK).

The only reasonable way to get this information is to query the database you are using to monitor the size of the [vault tables](https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.7/open-source/node-database-tables.html#vault-tables) throughout the lifecycle of the states and make some calculation.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I found this post https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.2/enterprise/sizing-and-performance.html#database-storage and I want to know if we can assume that the size of a state in a transaction is similar to the size of the transaction itself, just to have an idea of the database table space usage

Comment: Yes, they did what I suggested in my answer basically.